# Animated record deletion with jquery like mootools example

Tags: jquery, mootools

I was reading around and saw **[this example](http://davidwalsh.name/dw-content/mootools-record-delete.php)** from David Walsh about how to animate record deletion with mootools. I'd hate to add mootools to a project just to use this effect, so does the exact same effect exist in jquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something along these lines should work:

```
<style>
  .delete { border:solid 1px; cursor:pointer}
</style>

<div class='delete' id='record-0'>1</div>
<div class='delete' id='record-1'>2</div>
<div class='delete' id='record-2'>3</div>

<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.0/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script>
$('.delete').click(function() {
  $.post("/delete_script",
         {"delete":$(this).attr('id').replace('record-', '')},
         function(){$(this).slideToggle()})
  })
</script>
```

See also:  http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Comment: Not sure what you mean.  I'm seeing the sliding effect just fine in 1.4.4.  The slide only happens on successful completion of the ajax deletion, so if you are just running my snippet as an html file without a backend you're not going to see it.  If you get rid of  the post and just call slideToggle it should work fine.

Comment: the effect is different as jQuery's slide does not work like a real slide effect, it's a simple expand/collapse effect. You need special tailored code to emulate MooTools' Fx.Slide (there might be a jQuery plugin for that already, not sure) Note: Fx.Slide is part of the MooTools-More package, in case you want to take a look at the code.